# Update SQL using different table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

May I know how can I update using 2 different table. In my case update cust_invoice_index from table acc_doclink. But, in doclink, I want to update using sum(amount). Also, if there is null, the sum(amount) will be 0.

I have used these query based on other people asked in stackoverflow but still cannot do. I am using postgresql. Hope you guys can help me. Thank you.

1:

```
UPDATE cust_invoice_index as invoice 
LEFT JOIN (select tgt_docid,sum(amount) as sum_amount from acc_doclink where tgt_docref='cust_invoice_index' and status='active' group by tgt_docid) as doclink
ON invoice.pkid=doclink.tgt_docid
SET outstanding_amt=a.total_amt+coalesce(b.sum_amount,0) 
WHERE invoice.pkid=424382;
```

2:

```
UPDATE cust_invoice_index
SET invoice.outstanding_amt=invoice.total_amt+coalesce(doclink.sum(amount),0) 
FROM cust_invoice_index as invoice
LEFT JOIN acc_doclink as doclink
ON invoice.pkid=doclink.tgt_docid
WHERE invoice.pkid=424382;
```

3:

```
UPDATE invoice.outstanding_amt=invoice.total_amt+coalesce(doclink.sum(amount),0)
FROM cust_invoice_index as invoice
LEFT JOIN acc_doclink as doclink
ON invoice.pkid=doclink.tgt_docid
WHERE invoice.pkid=424382;
```

4:

```
UPDATE cust_invoice_index as invoice
SET invoice.outstanding_amt=invoice.total_amt+coalesce(doclink.sum(amount),0)
FROM acc_doclink as doclink
WHERE invoice.pkid=doclink.tgt_docid and invoice.pkid=424382;
```

5:

```
update cust_invoice_index as invoice
set outstanding_amt=total_amt+coalesce(doclink.sum(amount),0)
from acc_doclink as doclink
where invoice.pkid=doclink.tgt_docid and invoice.pkid=424382;
```

6:

```
update cust_invoice_index
set a.outstanding_amt=a.total_amt+coalesce(b.sum(amount),0)
from cust_invoice_index  as a
left join acc_doclink as b
on a.pkid=b.tgt_docid
where a.pkid=424382 and tgt_docref='cust_invoice_index';
```

Comment: The fourth and fifth variants above looks largely correct.  What error do you get from those?

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING will not get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to shout at the people you're asking to help you.

Comment: For the 4 I get this error: 
ERROR:  schema "doclink" does not exist
LINE 2: ...nvoice.outstanding_amt=invoice.total_amt+coalesce(doclink.su...

Comment: Please start your question by declaring your version of Postgres (always!) and basic table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements). It's currently unclear where `total_amt` comes from, and why you add to it, and whether it can be NULL, too.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Those are two very different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb, this might be your query:

```sql
UPDATE cust_invoice_index i
SET    outstanding_amt = i.total_amt + COALESCE((
         SELECT sum(amount)
         FROM   acc_doclink d
         WHERE  d.tgt_docref = 'cust_invoice_index'
         AND    d.status = 'active'
         AND    d.tgt_docid = i.pkid), 0)
WHERE  i.pkid = 424382;
```

This assumes that `total_amt` is a column of table `cust_invoice_index` and defined `NOT NULL`. (You did not specify.)

Since this only targets a single row (I assume), and while we don't know whether table `acc_doclink` is guaranteed to hold any related rows, I switched to a correlated subquery to ditch the dicey `LEFT JOIN` (which would make the JOIN syntax more complex).

If the target rows often does not actually change in this `UPDATE` a different style avoiding the empty update would be more efficient. But you'll have to provide proper information first ...